# Not a mandatory in type field Upload image in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

How i set the not mandatory in type field while  upload image in codeigniter?

Any one please answer to me??

Answer (score 0):

if the image field name is image, you can check the condition whether the file is exist r not like this..

```
if($_FILES['image']['name']!='')
{
............
............
}
```

if the file exist, u can upload the file...